# Как замедлить работу одной функции в цикле не затрагивая другие?

Tags: python, pygame

Я создаю игру где корабль должен уворачиваться от появляющихся пришельцев. В главном классе игры есть функция которая добавляет нового пришельца в группу. И я хочу замедлить эту функцию но когда я добавляю команду sleep замедляется весь цикл. Мне нужно чтобы пришельцы появлялись с заданным интервалом.

```
import sys

import pygame

from time import sleep

from settings import Settings

from rocket import Rocket

from bullet import Bullet

from alien import Alien


import asyncio

class Cosmos:
    """Главный класс игры Cosmos"""

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Cosmos')
        self.fon_image = pygame.image.load('image/Fon.png')
        self.fon = self.fon_image.get_rect()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.rocket = Rocket(self.screen, self.settings)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.alien = Alien(self.screen, self.settings)

    def key_event(self):
        """Обрабатывает нажатие клавиш"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.rocket.move_RIGHT = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.rocket.move_LEFT = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.rocket.move_UP = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.rocket.move_DOWN = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    new_bullet = Bullet(self.screen, self.settings, self.rocket)
                    self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    self.rocket.move_RIGHT = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    self.rocket.move_LEFT = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    self.rocket.move_UP = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    self.rocket.move_DOWN = False

    def spawn_alien(self):
        """Добавляет пришельца в группу"""
        alien = Alien(self.screen, self.settings)
        self.aliens.add(alien)


    def bullet_sprite(self):
        """Рисует и обновляет спрайт снаряда"""
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            if bullet.rect.x < 5000 and bullet.rect.x > 0 and bullet.rect.y < 1500 and bullet.rect.y > 0:
                bullet.draw_bullet()
                bullet.update()
            else:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

    def hui(self):


    def run_game(self):
        """Обновляет события игры"""
        while True:
            self.screen.blit(self.fon_image, self.fon)
            self.key_event()
            self.rocket.update_rocket()
            self.bullet_sprite()
            self.rocket.draw_rocket()            
            self.spawn_alien()
            self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
            print(self.aliens)
            pygame.display.flip()


game = Cosmos()
game.run_game()
```

---

```
import pygame

from pygame.sprite import Sprite

from random import randint


class Alien(Sprite):
    """Класс, представляющий одного пришельца"""

    def __init__(self, screen, settings):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.settings = settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image/pixil-frame-1.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = randint(0, 1800)
        self.rect.y = randint(0, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте, что прошло достаточно времени для создания нового пришельца:

```
ALIENS_PER_SECOND = 1

class Cosmos:
    """Главный класс игры Cosmos"""

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.aliens_spawned = 0
 
    def spawn_alien(self):
        """Добавляет пришельца в группу"""
        alien = Alien(self.screen, self.settings)
        self.aliens.add(alien)
        self.aliens_spawned += 1

    def run_game(self):
        """Обновляет события игры"""
        while True:
            ...
            if self.aliens_spawned < ALIENS_PER_SECOND * pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000:
                 self.spawn_alien()
```

Тут идет проверка, что пришельцев меньше чем должно быть исходя из прошедшего времени и скорости их генерация в единицу времени. И только если это так, то создаем нового. При `ALIENS_PER_SECOND = 1` будет создаваться один за секунду

Comment: Проблема в том что когда я убиваю пришельца то сразу появляется новый. Мне нужно реализовать логику так чтобы по игре был смысл убивать пришельца чтобы их становилось меньше.

Comment: Так, что вам мешает написать логику такую, как вы хотите? :) Проверяйте не текущее количество пришельцев (`len(self.alients)`), а сгенерированное с начала игры, т.е. храните в отдельной переменной сколько всего было сгенерировано, добавляйте по одному каждый раз, как генерируете, и эту переменную используйте в проверке.

Comment: Обновил ответ   .

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось